# Should a mortgage refinance bank be granted access to full tax returns of the last two years?

Tags: mortgage, loans

I'm shopping around to refinance my mortgage (in the USA) and one bank asked for the following information:

```
2018 & 2019 Tax Returns (All Pages)
2018 & 2019 W2
Most Recent Last 2 Paystubs If Paid Bi-Weekly, Most Recent Last 4 If Paid Weekly
Last 2 Months Bank Statements (All Pages)
Most Recent Retirement Statement (All Pages) If Quarterly Most Recent, If Monthly Last 2
```

That first one seems excessive to me. I can understand wanting proof of income, but surely a single page shows that, and they shouldn't have access to every detail about my finances like this.

Is this a reasonable or excessive requirement?

Comment: Whether or not it's reasonable/excessive is a matter of opinion, but it is standard practice.

Comment: @Hart CO: Yes, if you want to get a mortgage from them, it's reasonable to provide the info they ask for.  If you don't want to provide it, you look for another lender.  Also, they're probably getting the info direct from the IRS (because it would be so easy to fake a PDF), so getting just one page isn't really an option.

Comment: @jamesqf: a lot of money is involved here, so if you were that sort of person, couldn't you fake the whole thing?

Comment: @JoshuaFrank In addition to them getting the returns from the IRS directly, as most of my lenders have, sure it's possible to fake them - but it's more work than just lying about your income, and they're not trying to catch the 1% who are trying to rip them off; they're trying to catch the 20% who omit something, but aren't going to go to the length of falsifying a government form.

Comment: @Joshua Frank: What do you mean by "fake the whole thing"?  An entire tax return vs just one page?  Sure, no problem, which I assume is why they request copies of the return from the IRS.

Comment: If they can get the return from the IRS and are going to do so anyway, why do they ask me for them at all, instead of just asking for the authorization to get them>

Comment: Joshua: they normally do request only authorization, on 4506T[-EZ]. But a nit: what they actually get is a _transcript_ not the actual return, see https://www.irs.gov/individuals/international-taxpayers/income-verification-express-service .

Answer (score 2):

It is common practice in the US for the bank to ask for tax returns for the last two years.  Every mortgage and refinance I've had asked for both 1040 and W2 (usually just asking permission to get them from the IRS, which I assume makes them more confident I'm not fudging things).

This is explained to some extent in [this article](https://www.meridianhm.com/resource/blog/tax-returns-matter-mortgage/#:%7E:text=Lenders%20also%20ask%20for%20your,with%20your%20mortgage%20applica%2D%20tion.), which explains that tax returns include a lot of information about losses, writeoffs, etc., as well as:

> Your tax returns will also tell the lender if your home has any farm income, if you pay alimony, or if you have received unemployment income.

Those all can affect your approval (or your rate).  Farm income would make you ineligible for some mortgages, alimony would need to be disclosed, and of course unemployment income would be something they want to know about.

Comment: For divorces in 2019 and later (and earlier ones if explicitly modified) alimony paid (and received) is no longer on the 1040.

Answer (score 1):

For what it's worth - I refinanced my HELOC (Home Equity Loan) 3 years ago. The bank only needed our retirement account statements and proof of homeowner insurance. But, as we are retired, the tax returns wouldn't have been of too much value to them, anyway. Each situation is different, but yes, it's reasonable to ask for this.

It's good practice to keep copies of your returns for 7 years, minimum, and this shouldn't be a burden.

(On a complete tangent - My state replied to my 2019 return asking for a copy of my W2 (fine) along with a copy of my last pay stub for 2019. Last pay stub? Pay is direct deposited. When it hits the acct, who keeps the email? I had to spend the time to go into an early January hard drive back up to locate that email. That felt far more annoying than what the bank is asking. Yes, retired, but small part time gig that gives me a W2)

Comment: I always keep the last stub of the year for an employer. It has all the items that will appear on the W-2. It was very helpful when I had to complete FAFSA forms in January.

Comment: Yes. And I toss it (or in this case, deleted email) when the W2 arrives. Funny, the state tax withholding is what they wanted me to show proof of. The W2 job was <$300. And the $8000 or so was from withholding at the broker level, IRA withdrawals. The whole thing seemed odd to me. Lesson learned, I guess.